# set read only property to the ajax tab panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have to set ajax tab panel as in read only property as so its controls also must be have read only property. How can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the ajax tab panel inside a panel or div and you can disable that panel...

```
    <asp:Panel ID="PnlContact" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" >
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Contacts">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="InnerPanel" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Here you can make the Enabled property of `TabPanel1` from code behind..

```
TabPanel1.Enabled= false;
```

Comment: hi jameem...in the above example you showed the code to set readonly property to the entire tabcontainer....here i had multiple tab panel inside the content template so i have to set readonly property to the specific tab panel which is inside the contentTemlete?

Comment: Sorry,my mistake.You can use Enabled property of the panel..I hav updated the answer...

Comment: sorry, i have to set this property to the tabpanel not for the panel..is that possible?

Comment: If you insert a Panel inside the content template of your particular tab panel and set enabled property to false can solve the issue...I have checked in my project setting it,Regards...

Comment: if i set it like that is that can properly show the header tabs?

Comment: If you want to disable the whole tab including header you can just set an ID for tab panel and set its enabled property to False..Updated the answer..

Comment: no.i already did like that i want to make more dynamic but that not possible for my sceanrio...anyway thanks fro ur reply

Comment: What you mean by making more dynamic?From clientside?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking anything like this .

http://codeverge.com/asp.net.ajax_control_toolkit/how-to-enable-or-disable-asp.net/21378

Comment: yes.but there in a change in my point of view, if i set enable false to the ajax tab panel, it didn't loading its respective block.i was looked its class via developer tool, its applied disabled property to the specific tab panel.so i can i do that

Comment: if readOnly not supported. you can use pnlContact.Enabled = false;

Comment: thanks for ur reply...but i want to set enabled or readonly property to the tabpanel..if i set enabled false to the tabpanel its respective block doesn't loaded